# How can I multiplicate two arrays in a way that the first value of arrayA multiply the last value of arrayB?

Tags: java, arrays, multiplication

How can I multiplicate two arrays in a way that the first value of arrayA multiply the last value of arrayB?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int numbersA[] = new int[5];
    int numbersB[] = new int[5];
    int numbersC[] = new int[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < numbersA.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Please insert a number for the first array: ");
        numbersA[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbersA));

    for (int i = 0; i < numbersB.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Please insert a number for the second array: ");
        numbersB[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbersB));

    System.out.print("The multiplication of the two arrays (the first one with the last one and consecutively) are: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersC.length; i++) {
        numbersC[i] = numbersA[i] * numbersB[(numbersB.length) - 1 - i];
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbersC));
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first element(i.e. index 0) of **numbersA[ ]** should be multiplied by last element(i.e. index 9) of **numbersB[ ]** array. Similarly second element(i.e. index 1) of **numbersA[ ]** should be multiplied by second last element(i.e. index 8) of **numbersB[ ]**. Like shown below:

```
public static void main(String... ars) {

    System.out.println("enter the length of arrays");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int len = sc.nextInt();


    int numbersA[] = new int[len];
    int numbersB[] = new int[len];
    int numbersC[] = new int[len];

    Random rand = new Random();

    System.out.println("enter the values of first array");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersA.length; i++) {
        numbersA[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbersA));

    System.out.println("enter the values of second array");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersB.length; i++) {
        numbersB[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbersB));


    out.println("The multiplication of the two arrays (the first one with the last one and consecutively) are: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersC.length; i++) {
        numbersC[i] = numbersA[i] * numbersB[(numbersB.length)-1-i];
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbersC));
}
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly, my problem is that the arrays are not fixed, so I need to ask the user to imput it. can you please check on my code?

Comment: @John you mean the size of the array is not fixed right? and you have to take the length of the array as an input from user  but the length of both array will be same, am i correct?

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the inverse index from the second array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbersC.length; i++) {
    numbersC[i] = numbersA[i] * numbersB[numbersC.length - 1 - i];
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbersC));
```

This loop relies, of course, on all 3 arrays having the same length.

Comment: I corrected my code like you said but its not working, I edited the code so you can see it on my question in order to find my error

Comment: I corrected it, but it seems is still dont work, can you please check on it?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this its the same code you have done and its working fine as i checked it.

public class Test{

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int numbersA[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int numbersB[] = {5,4,3,2,1};
int numbersC[] = new int[5];


System.out.print("The multiplication of the two arrays (the first one with the last one and consecutively) are: ");
for (int i = 0; i < numbersC.length; i++) {
    numbersC[i] = numbersA[i] * numbersB[(numbersB.length) - 1 - i];
        System.out.println(numbersC[i]);
}
```

}
}